# Why did Dolores never react to Bruno?

Tags: encanto

Near the middle of Encanto, there's a big reveal that:

> Bruno never left the house

Given that Dolores has super hearing, why does she never mention anything about that or have a reaction?

At the end she sings:

> Yo, I knew he never left I heard him every day

I know "we don't talk about Bruno" is a bit of a thing, but I'd expect her to have at least reacted at some point, out of fear or otherwise, when she realised what she was hearing.

My only other conclusion is she was bluffing in the closing song, but then why couldn't she hear him?

Which is it?

Comment: _”The only one worried about the magic is you and the rats talking in the walls.”_

Comment: Why would she react to something she's been hearing for ten years? As you said, he's been there the whole time. She may have reacted the first time she heard him, but by the time the film starts, it'd be just background noise to her, like everyone else in the Encanto.

Comment: @F1Krazy they seemed pretty reactionary whenever they even say his *name*, I don't think some reaction is that much of a stretch ...

Answer (score 3):

Presumably she's afraid that if she says something, the wrath of Bruno will descend upon her, noting that she

> *"...grew to live in fear of Bruno, stuttering or stumbling."*

and that

> *"...She could always hear him sort of muttering and mumbling"*

Since the Encanto is an enclosed space, it's not really clear where people think he went, but the familia know he's still alive and living aroundabout.

Comment: Ahhh of course. Perhaps she knew, or perhaps she assumed she heard him from much further away.